# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to compile my first iOS Hello app.

## I have

**ViewController.swift**

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  My First Project

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Declare components
    @IBOutlet weak var inputLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        
    }

    @IBAction func submitBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        inputLabel.text = "Hello World"
        
    }
    
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

---

## I Kept

getting `Build Succeeded`

[image]

But after about 5 seconds, I got this

[image]

---

## Console Error

[image]

```
         0x0000000103915f69 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010770f723 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010770f59c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010770f925 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ff0311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105fd559c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105fd4a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105fd4494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001039147e6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010391a964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  My First Project                    0x0000000102e6db3f main + 111
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106f7868d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

---

## Try #1

### Connection Inspector

I used to have this

[image]

I updated to this

[image]

Re-run and still happening ...

---

## Try #2

### Clean project

Re-run and still happening ...

Comment: There will be an error message in the console telling you what the exception is

Comment: @DávidPásztor : As request, I updated my post with AppDelegate code.

Comment: @dan : I've added my console error, do you have any suggestion base on that. I tried create a new project make a simple lablel, just 1, run the app,  and still seeing this issue even if I only have 1 label.

Comment: @ihue just remove ALL connections to that viewController...and then connect inputLabel again...

Comment: @ihue can you share your "my first iOS Hello app" code ? It would be easy to fix your problems.

Comment: I'd honestly try a brand new project. Start from scratch. The small amount of code you've shown - likely an MVCE - is good. Tap or click a button (typed as Any) and update a label. Yes, I'm giving not the *best* answer - assuming your actual code contains much more - but that's why you do backups. **Something** is wrong. Xcode says such. Sometimes you need to "roll back" to a working point.

Comment: Had You changed the name of label used and button Action declaration after connecting a outlet ? if no, just try again connecting a fresh outlet by first removing from storyboard. it should Work or if still not please share your Xcode Project

Answer (score 12):

Issue is in your labels, I am 100% sure you have deleted some outlet references and forget to remove the connection from story board. Please check

Answer (score 6):

This problem happens when you delete referencing outlet in your `ViewController` and forget to remove the connection from `storyboard`.

**Perfect connection ✅**

The perfect referencing outlet looks like below screenshot.

[image]
[image]

> Now let's delete the referencing outlet from `.h` file

**Problem ⚠️**

if we remove referencing outlet from `.h` file Xcode will give warning in Storyboard. this is the trick you can find which outlet was deleted from the class.

i hope this will help you .

[image]

[image]

**Solution**

In your case you may have  changed the name `lable` to `inputLable` so you need to do :

Remove the connection to `label`.
Re-Connect the controller to `inputLabel`.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>There is an inconsistency in code and screenshot.</strike>

- Code: `label.text = "Hello World"`
- Screenshot: `inputLabel.text = "Hello World"`

The error message is :

> ... is not key-value compliant for the key **label**.

So most likely in your actual code the `IBOutlet` is named `inputLabel` but in Interface Builder there is a (dead) connection to `label` which causes the crash.

**Solution:**

- Select `Main.storyboard` in the navigation bar and `ViewController` in the canvas.
- Open the Connections Inspector (<kbd>⌥⌘6</kbd>)
- Remove the connection to `label`.
- Connect the controller to `inputLabel`.

Comment: I'm sorry for not catch that deprecated code. I updated my post to be consistent now.

Comment: It doesn't affect the suggestion to fix the issue.

Comment: Ok. I added a screenshot of my connection inspector. Are they look correct ?

Comment: No, they are not: I wrote ***Remove the connection to `label`*** Click on the `x`

Comment: I see that comment. I removed it, re-run, still happening.

Comment: Clean the project (press ⇧⌘K), then build and run.

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F, type `label` and return. Are they search results (just `label` not `inputLabel` !)

Comment: I have about 8 objects in my `Main.storyboard` , but I only have my button and my label hooking up in my `ViewController.swift` - do I need to declare all the objects ? do u think this might be the issue ? Please kindly advise.

Comment: The error is distinctly related to `ViewController`. Remove the other (proper) connection, too and reconnect the outlet.

Comment: What are the (proper) connection ? label and button ?

Comment: Only the label outlet. If the error still occurs, is it still exactly the same error message?

Comment: I will go ahead and do that. Will update you shortly.

Comment: Delete all the objects components, and leave only label. Clean the project, re-run, it finally working now. How often should I clean my project ?

Comment: Cleaning is useful after changing connections and bindings in IB.

Comment: Ohh okay got it - will do from now.

Answer (score 2):

have u checked default IBOutlet of view.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the storyboard elements are connected to the outlets in your code. Try to delete all the connections in the connections inspector and reconnect the elements

When you go to main.storyboard, on the right you have a panel, the most right one os the connections inspector. In there you have to delete al the connection by pressing the little 'x' in the connections.

It should look somewhat familiar like this, but different names
[in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12kMf.png)

delete all of them

also in your viewController.swift file, remove all the @IBOutlet lines.

Then connect your outlets again to your ViewController.swift file, which you did before

For just changing a label in code it finally should look like this [final screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq4Uf.png)

mind the outlet on the right

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Which should I look into to check that  ? ViewController.swift ?

Comment: I think you don't make your outlets properly, you have to control drag them to your viewcontroller and give them a name. Not just typing the code `@IBOutlet label: UILabel!` because your code don't have a reference to your label by this

Answer (score 1):

It crashed because you removed your `IBOutlet` `label` in your code of `ViewController.swift` without removing the `connection` on Storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

To solve this problem, right click on `inputLabel` in `storyboard`, click the 'x' button at `label` connection like this:
[image: Remove removed connection]

> Note: Please don't forget remove the connection in storyboard before
>   removing your IBOutlet in code.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned about outlets and its references which you have to make sure about them that they have connected correctly in to your class.

Another possible case comes to my mind may be this : If you have define a key path for your label under `user defined Rundtime Attributes` in the `identity inspector` tab in storyboard, and if the key is undefined, you will get this message error in your console log :

```
...this class is not key-value compliant for the key label.
```

e.g. in the image below you see a key path `popupTitle` if it is not defined in your class of label it will get this error message. and in some cases it will crash. Make sure you don't have extra key path in this section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I was copying some files from another project (and renaming them). Xcode got confused and apparently struggled with connecting outlets. In Xcode everything looked fine, but I was stuck with the same error as in the question on runtime, with no further explanation.

I fixed it by cleaning the project and deleting derived data. As always.. :/