# How do I fix ,Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, in my code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am having trouble with my code everything was working fine and then I started to get this error

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value"

The error is occurring when I am letting my cell variable be a Reusable cell.

Here is my code, the error is occurring on line 3 where let cell is being declared.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let song = songs[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SongCell") as! SongCell
    cell.setSong(song: song)
    return cell
}
```

Update: I have fixed the Fatal error but I am now getting

> "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

The error is occurring when I add this code to set a table views data source and delegate.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            songs = createArray()
            playlists = createArray2()
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView2.dataSource = self    //Adding this causes app to crash
            tableView2.delegate = self  //Adding this causes the app to crash

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Whenever I remove this code the app launches but no cells show in the table view.

Comment: This could be a problem casting the cell to your SongCell type (as!). Is the cell in the storyboard definitely the correct class?

Comment: Most likely the class of the custom cell is not set to `SongCell` in Interface Builder. And as suggested in the answer use the `dequeueReusableCell` API with the `indexPath` parameter (which is actually not the reason of the crash).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second argument of `dequeueReusableCell`

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SongCell", for: indexPath) as! SongCell
```

Make sure to register a nib or class

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NibSongCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SongCell")
```

OR

```
// if using a custom cell, replace UITableViewCell.self with that class
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SongCell")
```

Comment: check this out the new issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/44439343/1244597

Comment: It's now giving me "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error in my app delegate file. It is occurring on this line "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {". I have checked all of my labels and outputs for errors but their aren't any.

Comment: If the cell is designed in Interface Builder as prototype cell you **must not** register the cell.